# How can I change gap length between the hills?

Tags: periodic-functions

I drew hills by using `max(sin(x),0)` that you can see this on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3tw5uiavhl).

[image: hill]

I need to change distance between hills without changing size.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short solution for any gap $g$.

In desmos enter the following:
[image: hills with arbitrary gaps]

Move the $g$-slider to see the gaps changing size.

Here you see, how it is built:

[image]

Comment: well done :D It works thanks I done [link in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u9bqbgacde) can you explain how it works?

Comment: The function $p$ makes it periodic. It takes on only values within the interval $[o,\pi+g)$. It is derived from $x-floor(x)$ which gives you a way to bring a period into a function.
The function $s$ "lives" only on the interval $[0,\pi]$ with a value of 1, otherwise 0. 
Now, combining this, you make the expression periodic with function $p$ but let the $\sin(x)$ only "live" on $[0,\pi]$ using function $s$.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). Using this, we can make the function $x$ "skip forward" at even intervals, thus shortening the gaps exactly the way we want. So, we are going to use the setup $\max(0, \sin(h_1(x)))$, where $h_1(x) = x + c\lfloor h_2(x)\rfloor$ for some $h_2(x) = ax + b$ that we will have to construct and some constant $c$.

So, in order to figure out what we want from $h_2(x)$, we need to figure out what we want from $h_1$. We want some fixed period $\pi + k$ such that in one period $h_1(x)$ increases by exactly $2\pi$. We want $h_1(x)$ to have slope $1$ for the most part (this is achieved by the $x$ term), and then have a jump discontinuity once per period, which is achieved by $a\lfloor h_2(x)\rfloor$.

How large is this jump discontinuity (controlled by $c$), and how often ant at what points will they happen (controlled by $a$ and $b$)? Well, one period is $\pi +k$, and we want the graph to increase by $2\pi$ in this time, so the remaining $\pi - k$ change in function value will have to be done by the discontinuity jumps. The jumps of the floor function are $1$, so that means that $c = \pi - k$.

The frequency of the gaps (controlled by $a$) next: The period is $\pi + k$, and for each period we need exactly one skip. That means that $h_2(x)$ has to increase in value by exactly $1$ each period. So $a = \frac1{\pi + k}$.

Finally, the position of the jump, controlled by $b$. We can basically put this wherever we want in the gap, but I'll place it at the end of the gap, because that's easiest. One end of a gap happens right at $x = 0$, so we want $h_2(0)$ to be an integer, which makes $b = 0$ a really simple choice.

So that's it. We now have the function
$$
\max(0, \sin(h_1(x))) = \max\left(0,\sin\left( x +(\pi - k)\lfloor h_2(x)\rfloor\right)\right)\\
= \max\left(0,\sin\left( x +(\pi - k)\left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi + k}\right\rfloor\right)\right) 
$$
and a [Desmos link here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lg5gr5hnec) (I don't know for how long that link will keep working, though).

Fair warning: This really cannot cope with a gap larger than $\pi$. If you plot $\sin(h_1(x))$ as well, or just extend the range of $k$, you can see what happens. If we instead put the jump in the middle of the gap (which requires some more working-out of $b$, since instead of $h_2(0)$ to be an integer, you want $h_2(-k/2)$ to be an integer), then this can handle a gap of up to $2\pi$.

Comment: thanks but I need to test your formula.I'm very weak in math can you give me executable of you formula in desmos?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamaly I tried for a few minutes, and it turns out to be quite difficult. I couldn't really do it without resorting to splitting into cases and using periodicity in some way. Maybe someone else will spot some clever trick that I couldn't find. If it Desmos had a builtin triangle wave, that would help a lot, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamaly It does have a floor function, I think I can mock something up with that. Gimme a few minutes.

Comment: thanks man you're the best.no problem I'm waiting :)

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamaly Try it now.

Comment: worked! worked! thanks.but when I change 3.14 to another number it have problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73185/discussion-between-seyed-morteza-kamaly-and-arthur).